# Are the counters limited in Wrath of Ashardalon?

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

In the new D+D game **Wrath of Ashardalon**, suppose that you use a daily power that places counters (like **Blade Barrier**, **Mirror Image**, or **Flaming Sphere**) and then get the power refreshed (through an item, for example) while the counters are still on the board.

Can you use the power again, and if so, what happens (given that you don't have enough counters left to place more)?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an official ruling, but the way I've seen it played is, when a daily power is used a second time, all related tokens are removed from the board and placed again by the player according to the rules of that power.